# I had wrote an sql query in php can any one suggest this code will work?

Tags: php, sql, connection

$data=  mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *, ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `lat` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( '$slat' ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `lat` ) ) * COS( RADIANS( '$slat' )) * COS(RADIANS( `lon` ) - RADIANS( '$slon' )) ) * 6380 AS `distance` FROM `doner` WHERE ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `lat` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( '$slat' ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `lat`) ) * COS( RADIANS( '$slat' )) * COS( RADIANS( `lon` ) - RADIANS( '$slon' )) ) * 6380 < '$dist' AND  blood='$blood' ORDER BY `distance`");

Comment: Can't you test by yourself if the code works or not before asking us to do the job for your?

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if I am wrong but, it seems to be your first topic on this site. My advice is to put this code in "code sample" like this if you want to increase your chance someone answer your question :

```
$request = "
        SELECT *, ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( lat ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( '$slat' ) ) + COS( RADIANS( lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( '$slat' )) * COS(RADIANS( lon ) - RADIANS( '$slon' )) ) * 6380 AS distance 
        FROM doner 
        WHERE ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( lat ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( '$slat' ) ) + COS( RADIANS( lat) ) * COS( RADIANS( '$slat' )) * COS( RADIANS( lon ) - RADIANS( '$slon' )) ) * 6380 < '$dist' 
        AND blood='$blood' 
        ORDER BY distance
";

$data= mysqli_query($con, $request);
```

For my own opinion, it's difficult to have an idea of what this code does (SQL meaningly) because we haven't your data bases, tables, and no clue of which calculus do.